# Exception when converting nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, type-conversion, nvarchar

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server 2014, which basically copies the data from one table to another if it doesn't exist on second table. When copying it has to make some conversions, because all columns in first table are `nvarchar`.
Almost every time I execute this procedure, I get the conversion error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I inserted try-catch instructions to get the errors, but it didn't help me very much. Also, I decided to use an auxiliary variable (`@aux`), to help me check on what point of the procedure the error is happening, since I don't have permission to debug the procedure on SSMS.

I think that I am getting this error because of the format of the date, or maybe culture. I do have rows in my first table with dates like '00-00-0000', and that's why it is `varchar`, also I make an IF statement in my procedure to replace these when copying.

Here's my procedure:

```
BEGIN try
    DECLARE crPESSOA_MKT CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            cpf, nome, nascimento, sexo, endereco, numero, complemento, 
            bairro, cidade, estado, cep, email, telefone, celular, receber_emails, qtde_codigos 
        FROM dbo.CLIENTESMKT2019 
        WHERE cpf IS NOT NULL

    DECLARE @Cpf nvarchar(255), @nome nvarchar(255), @nascimento datetime, 
            @sexo nvarchar(255), @endereco nvarchar(255), @numero nvarchar(255), 
            @complemento nvarchar(255), @bairro nvarchar(255), @cidade nvarchar(255), 
            @estado nvarchar(255), @cep nvarchar(255), @email nvarchar(255), 
            @telefone nvarchar(255), @celular nvarchar(255), @receber_emails nvarchar(255), 
            @qtde_codigos float, @data_errada nvarchar(255), @aux varchar(50)

    OPEN crPESSOA_MKT

    SET @aux = 'open'

    FETCH NEXT FROM crPESSOA_MKT INTO @Cpf, @nome, @nascimento, @sexo, @endereco, @numero, @complemento, @bairro, @cidade, @estado, @cep, @email, @telefone, @celular, @receber_emails, @qtde_codigos

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @aux = CONCAT('while ',@nascimento)
        SET @nascimento = FORMAT(@nascimento, 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'pt-BR')
        SET @aux = CONCAT('nascimento = ', @nascimento)

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT PESSOA.CPF FROM PESSOA 
                       WHERE PESSOA.CPF = LEFT(CAST(@Cpf AS VARCHAR), 11))
        BEGIN
            SET @aux = 'if exists'

            IF ISDATE(@nascimento) = 0 OR 
               @nascimento = CAST('00-00-0000' AS DATE) OR 
               YEAR(@nascimento) < 1900
            BEGIN
                SET @aux = 'if isdate'
                SET @nascimento = CAST('01-01-1900' AS DATE)
                SET @aux = 'set @nascimento'
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @aux = 'else'
                SET @nascimento = CAST(@nascimento AS DATE)
                SET @aux = 'cast nascimento'
            END

            SET @data_errada = CAST(@nascimento AS NVARCHAR)
            SET @aux = 'errados'

            INSERT INTO dbo.PESSOA (CPF, NOME, ENDERECO, BAIRRO, CIDADE, CEP, COMPLEMENTO,
                                    EMAIL, DATA_NASCIMENTO, FONE, ESTADO, SEXO, 
                                    CELULAR, RECEBE_EMAILSN, QTD_CUPONS, NUMERO, IDORIGEM, DATA_INCLUSAO)
            VALUES (LEFT(@cpf, 11), LEFT(@nome, 50), LEFT(@endereco, 50), LEFT(@bairro, 50), LEFT(UPPER(@CIDADE), 50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS, LEFT(@cep, 8), LEFT(@complemento, 50),
                    LEFT(@email, 50), @nascimento, LEFT(@telefone, 12), LEFT(@estado, 2), LEFT(@sexo, 1),
                    LEFT(@celular, 11), LEFT(@receber_emails, 1), @qtde_codigos, LEFT(CAST(@numero AS NVARCHAR), 15), 8, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

            SET @aux = 'insert'
        END
        /* ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT PESSOA.CPF FROM PESSOA 
                       WHERE PESSOA.CPF  = LEFT(CAST(@Cpf AS VARCHAR), 11))
            BEGIN
                SELECT EMAIL, LEFT(@email, 50) 
                FROM PESSOA 
                WHERE PESSOA.CPF = LEFT(CAST(@Cpf AS VARCHAR), 11)

                -- UPDATE PESSOA 
                -- SET EMAIL = LEFT(@email, 50)
                -- WHERE PESSOA.CPF  = LEFT(CAST(@Cpf AS VARCHAR), 11)
                --   AND EMAIL IS NULL
            END
        END*/      

        FETCH NEXT FROM crPESSOA_MKT INTO @Cpf, @nome, @nascimento,@sexo,@endereco,@numero,@complemento,@bairro,@cidade,@estado,@cep,@email,@telefone,@celular,@receber_emails,@qtde_codigos
        SET @aux = 'next'
    END

    CLOSE crPESSOA_MKT
    DEALLOCATE crPESSOA_MKT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
        @nascimento AS 'nascimento',
        @data_errada AS 'data errada',
        @aux AS 'aux'
END CATCH
```

and here's a result I got:

[image]

**EDIT**

Here's one of the registers that got me the error. The yellow value is my date column. Even if it is '0000-00-00', shouldn't the procedure change it when executing the IF statement?
[image]

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but *why* are you using a `CURSOR` to do what looks like it should be a set based method? As for your question **consumable** sample data, and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: this cursor was developed by an older developer, he said it worked last year and told me to use the same procedure, but I am having these problems. I will provide some sample data in a moment.

Comment: Here's a sample of my data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18xypl80HIsx5NR1FK42Fcyiy07z16lUda66is3om2lg/edit?usp=sharing
first 7 rows were inserted correctly in my second table, and last 2 rows are giving me the error

Comment: I recently hand crafted some SQL, and cobbled something together from something I got off SO somewhere. In that, the syntax was `CAST(N'2019-01-01 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime)`. Not sure what the N prefix does in front of the string in the cast. But that did the trick for me. Let me know if it helps. That was YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ttt format. Maybe the date that it bombs on may give you a clue - so it may be expecting YYYY-MM-DD format in your case.

Comment: Put the information in your post, @Gabic . I, and other users, are not going to trust a link to a google doc from a stranger.

Comment: @JGFMK tried to use the N on the strings, and tried to invert the date formats to yyyy-MM-dd and even remove the culture from format function, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Larnu how do I put the information on the post? It is a spreadsheet with the 16 columns of the table

Comment: Can you print out what the values were in the nvarchar when you got the out of range issue. Then post that back in your question. That will likely give you the pointer to what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs on this line -->

```
FETCH NEXT FROM crPESSOA_MKT INTO @Cpf, @nome, @nascimento
```

You are attempting to force a string in the form of '0000-00-00' into the DATETIME variable @nascimento which leads to an invalid conversion.

If this is the only edge case in the data you are importing then as a work around  check for validity and convert '000-00-00' to null (which I bet is the intention of that value anyway).

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     cpf, nome, CASE WHEN ISDATE(nascimento) THEN nascimento ELSE NULL END , sexo, endereco, numero, complemento,
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I used this `CASE` statement and modified my `IF` logic to check for null instead of invalid values, and the precedure executed completely fine!